# Validating URL paramaters

Tags: python, django

How should one validate URL parameters in a view? Would this be accomplished using a a bunch of `ìf` statements or is there a better way to go about it? I'd like to validate the parameters when the request comes in rather than having it scattered across my view, model and manager.

When I say validation I'm referring to basic checks such as existence of a key, checking the data type, integer ranges, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case it depends on the scale of your application
if it's just a small application doing data validation via simple if statements
would be the easiest route, but django does have features to support nicer form validation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/), so it 
might be cleaner to do it that way, but it still boils down to if statements in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your `urls.py` can take care of some of the validation with an appropriate regex (e.g., use `\d` for integer values instead of `\w`) but existence of a key or anything more sophisticated has to do be done in your view code itself, typically with if checks.

Key existence validation logic can be simplified with [django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) or using a base view class or decorator though.